# Should conversion operators be considered for function template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/EhE98j):

```
template<typename>
struct S 
{
    operator S<int&>();  
};

template<typename T>
void f(S<T&>);

int main() 
{
    f(S<int&&>{});  // gcc ok
                    // clang error
}
```

gcc uses the conversion operator on the temporary argument, returning `S<int&>` which is matched by `S<T&>`, and accepts the call.

clang doesn't consider the conversion operator, fails to match `T&` against `int&&`, and rejects the call.

So what does the language say should happen here?

Comment: I was confused, please ignore that. Template argument deduction fails, overload resolution fails, and nothing more is considered, at least so I think.

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, deduction fails, but only in one case and not the other. I want to know which one, if any, is correct.

Comment: By that I mean gcc is wrong.

Comment: @PasserBy Ok, thanks. If you can find a bug report, that would be great. If you know *why* gcc is wrong, then an answer would be lovely as well.

Comment: gcc rejects `f(S<int>{})`, which should be a pretty clear sign.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, that seems reasonable.

Comment: [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) could help. I guess clang is right on this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is certainly wrong here: `T&` and `T&&` are different rows in [temp.deduct.type]/8 and are thus incompatible.  Why it does so is not clear.  It would make more sense to err in the other direction: if the parameter were declared as `S<T&&>` and the argument were of type `S<int&>`, there would at least be a `T` (*i.e.*, `int&`) such that (due to reference collapsing) the parameter and argument types were the same.  (There would also be the easy mistake to make to say that a universal reference was involved.)